# IOS: Is it possible to completely create/change/manipulate views from a background task

Tags: ios

We have a Voip SW that runs on a hardware phone. The hw phone has a touch screen with different screens/buttons/lists... The touch screen is manged by a rendering module that gets its information (like create button at position, subscreen on position,.. from another module (forms module). Now i'm wondering if it is even possible to implement such a rendering module on IOS? That would mean going completely without storyboards, any predefined layout and completely and asyncronously creating/changing views from a background task on the fly. I know that it's possible to create views on a background thread and push them on the main thread, i just wonder about the pitfalls (size classes, performance,..) of such an approach.

Answer (score 0):

From the little I know of your project's goals and little experience I have with this library, it sounds like you might be well served by [AsyncDisplayKit](http://asyncdisplaykit.org). It is a framework designed to allow as much of the view code as possible to be executed on background threads. Generally it is used to aide in improving UI responsiveness but it may be helpful here.

In general though, you are going to have to go to the main thread to safely do most anything with `UIKit` classes.